# ExtJS automation using Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, extjs4, ui-automation

Im trying to do automation testing in ExtJS application. I tried all possibilities by giving `id`, `cssSelector` and parent child hierarchy, still I not able to click a single button. Please suggest me some idea or any plugin to get it work.

Comment: show us page source so we can help.

Comment: a single button is bounded by multiple div's with auto generated id, i have accordions, tab panel, calendar pagination everything.. as i have limitation here cant add an image also..